# pl sql writing a function using 3 tables

Tags: sql, plsql

i have a column named assign_to in pby table, in assign_to i have users, roles as data when i select users i has to retrieve that users details from pus table, when i select roles i has to retrieve that roles details from pro table using a pl/sql function. can anyone please help me out from this???

```
case
when assign_to='users'
then (select users from pus where pby.id=pus.id)
assign_to='roles 
then (select roles from pro where pro.id=pby.id)
else null
end
```

i tried using case statement but it is not working.

Comment: "*it is not working*" is not an acceptable problem description

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing quotation mark for 'roles'.
Try this:

```
case 
when assign_to='users' then (select users from pus where pby.id=pus.id) 
when assign_to='roles' then (select roles from pro where pro.id=pby.id) 
else null 
end
```

Comment: Well, you should just add it to your pl/sql function.